# This server supports insecure Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange parameters (Logjam). Grade set to F

Tags: security, ssl, configuration

Recently i have renewed my website certificates and configured SSL. After that I tested my website : SSL Server Test(unable to post link here as I have less reputation).

It graded my website to "F". please refer to bellow image.

[SSL Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HASnD.jpg)

and it was mentioned in the test summery that 
"This server supports insecure Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange parameters (Logjam). Grade set to F". To avoid Logjam attack i followed the instructions given in this link: [Guide to Deploying Diffie-Hellman for TLS](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html)

I followed the solution provided by them then I changed the ciphers in my server.xml. my ciphers are:

```
<Connector SSLCipherSuite="ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA"
```

and tried to test the website again. The result didn't change, my website grade is still "F". **How do i avoid "Logjam attack"?** **Can I/My customer trust my website is secure?** or **It is vulnerable to attacks?**

I am using apache tomcat 7 server.

Any information or help would really help me. If anymore information is required please ask me.

Comment: ssllabs caches the test results, be sure to click "Clear cache" on the results page.

Comment: Yes, I did that every time I tested.

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat, the correct attribute is `ciphers`, not `SSLCipherSuite`:

```
<Connector
    ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA"
/>
```

`SSLCipherSuite` is used with apache http server.

Comment: I tried it.. but got this error while starting the server: **WARNING: None of the ciphers specified are supported by the SSL engine**.. and server is unable to start after i set ciphers property.. so I have changed it to **SSLCipherSuite**..

Comment: Did you also change the format of the ciphers? For tomcat it should be comma separated list, and also the names of the ciphers are different.